# A different symmetric algo for gpgme

Tags: ruby, gnupg, gpgme

By default, gpg2 uses CAST5 for a symmetric encryption. Here

```
crypto = GPGME::Crypto.new()
r = crypto.encrypt "Hello world!\n", symmetric: true
```

`r.read()` will return CAST5 data.

How to change the default cipher algo to, for example, AES256?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, apparently it's not possible to change the cipher through the API, but *is* possible w/ an indirect trick.

1. Create a tmp directory `/foo/bar` & put in it `gpg.conf` file w/ the line:

   ```
   personal-cipher-preferences aes256
   ```
2. Set a 'home' directory for gpgme (before `GPGME::Crypto.new`):

   ```
   GPGME::Engine.home_dir = '/foo/bar'
   ```